# How to read export memory profiler - android studio 3.2.1

Tags: android-studio-3.0, android-profiler

I am getting export from `memory profiler` and get me `memory-20181208T151741.alloc`, where can I read it?

Comment: Click on `Export heap dump` and you should get a `memory-someNumber.hprof` file. That file you can just open with Android Studio.  Just pull it from the explorer onto Android Studio.